# Adding conditional statements to a SQL window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, window-functions

I want to use a series of conditions to dictate how a window function I have works. Currently, what I have is this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
   1=Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 ASC) OR
   3=Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 ASC)
   AS col3 
FROM   myTable;
```

What it's essentially doing is taking two columns of input, grouping by the values in `col1`, ordering by values in `col2`, and then splitting the data for each partition into two halves, and flagging the first row of each half as a true/1.

So, taking this input:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

We get this result:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |    0 |
|    1 |    3 |    1 |
|    1 |    4 |    0 |
|    2 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |    0 |
|    2 |    3 |    1 |
|    2 |    4 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
```

Now, obviously, this only works when there are exactly 4 rows of entries for each value in `col1`. How do I introduce conditional statements to make this work when there aren't exactly 4 rows?

The constraints I have are these:

```
a) there will always be an even number of rows (2,4,6..) when grouping by values in `col1`
b) there will be a minimum of 2 rows when grouping by values in `col1`
```

EDIT:

I think I need to clarify that I do not simply want alternating rows of 1's and 0's. For example, if I used this table instead...

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
|    1 |    5 |
|    1 |    6 |
|    1 |    7 |
|    1 |    8 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    2 |    5 |
|    2 |    6 |
|    2 |    7 |
|    2 |    8 |
+------+------+
```

...then I'd expect this result:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |    0 |
|    1 |    3 |    0 |
|    1 |    4 |    0 |
|    1 |    5 |    1 |
|    1 |    6 |    0 |
|    1 |    7 |    0 |
|    1 |    8 |    0 |
|    2 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |    0 |
|    2 |    3 |    0 |
|    2 |    4 |    0 |
|    2 |    5 |    1 |
|    2 |    6 |    0 |
|    2 |    7 |    0 |
|    2 |    8 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
```

In the original example I gave, we grouped by `col1` and saw that there were 4 rows for each partition. We take half of that, which is 2, and flag every 2nd row (every other row) as true/1.

In this second example, once we group by `col1`, we see that there are 8 rows for each partition. Splitting that in half gives us 4, so every 4th row should be flagged with a true/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modulo arithmetic.

Many dialects of SQL use `%` for modulus:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) % 2 as col3
FROM mytable;
```

Some use the function `MOD()`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
       MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2), 2) as col3
FROM mytable;
```

EDIT:

You don't want to alternate rows.  You simply want two rows.  For that, you can still use modulo arithmetic but with somewhat different logic:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) %
        FLOOR(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) / 2)
       ) as col3
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Please see my edit. This doesn't work as expected beyond my original example case.

Answer (score 1):

I am just extending the Gordon's answer as his answer will not give you correct result -

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) %
        FLOOR(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) / 2) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       ) as col3
FROM mytable;
```